# Error: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle, odbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to set up a connection to an external server and am receiving the following message

ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified

I get this error message in both ODBC and SQL Plus

I just configured the oracle client on my windows server

Anyone have any idea what that might be?

My scenery:

Configure the Oracle Client then an ODBC and finally create a linked server on the sql server.

My File TNSNAMES.ora

```
devDB =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.40.22.6)(PORT = 1521))
(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SID = dev)
(FAILOVER_MODE =
(TYPE = SELECT)
(METHOD = BASIC)
(RETRIES = 180)
(DELAY = 5)
)
)
)
```

Comment: How can you have `LOAD_BALANCE = yes` and failover with only one host?

Comment: You will have to tell us what your database name is. Based on the error you do reach the `LISTENER` on the other side but it doesn't know the database you want to connect to. You specified `SID = dev` so you want to connect to a database with the name `dev`. If your database isn't called that way than here is your error. Note, you should use `SERVICE_NAME` as this will give you advantages if your database itself ever changes.